# $scope.$apply not updating on page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr

I have subscribed to signalr events. On notification updating textbox using $scope.$apply. Everything works fine. If page is refreshed using F5 or browser reload button, I am receiving signalr events but, textbox is not getting updated.

I am missing anything?

On notification

```
   signalRHub.client.Notify = function (data) {

        $scope.$apply(function () {
             $scope.upgradeResult += data.Message;
        });

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 1):

What browser version are you using? If you are testing using IE, even the F5/Refresh would retrieve the cached page unless you change the settings under Internet Options->General tab->Browsing History subsection->Settings
By default- Check for versions of stored pages is selected as 'Automatic'. Modify this to 'Every time I visit the page' - this should bypass caching the page and changes made on the page should reflect. Although this may not resolve your impediment if caching is not the issue, but it is a useful tip to consider nevertheless to avoid caching problems.

Comment: I am using Firefox - 39.0.3